# Gulp imagemin dest.on is not a function error

Tags: javascript, node.js, console, gulp, imagemin

I'm trying to minify images with imagemin, but it falls with an error.
Can't understand what I've done wrong.

Here is my gulpfile

```js
'use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp');
var imagemin = require('imagemin');
var clean = require('gulp-clean');

gulp.task('img', function () {
  return gulp.src('src/img/**')
    .pipe(imagemin())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build/img'));
});

gulp.task('clean', function() {
  console.log('-----------удаляю build');
  return gulp.src('build', {read: false})
    .pipe(clean());
});
```

And an error message from console

```
$ gulp img
(node:14312) fs: re-evaluating native module sources is not supported. If you are using the graceful-fs module, please update it to a more recent version.
[22:10:20] Using gulpfile Z:\a\gulpfile.js
[22:10:20] Starting 'img'...
[22:10:20] 'img' errored after 26 ms
[22:10:20] TypeError: dest.on is not a function
    at DestroyableTransform.Readable.pipe (Z:\a\node_modules\vinyl-fs\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_readable.js:516:8)
    at Gulp.<anonymous> (Z:\a\gulpfile.js:9:6)
    at module.exports (Z:\a\node_modules\orchestrator\lib\runTask.js:34:7)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator._runTask (Z:\a\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:273:3)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator._runStep (Z:\a\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:214:10)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator.start (Z:\a\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:134:8)
    at C:\Users\Artur\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\gulp-cli\lib\versioned\^3.7.0\index.js:46:20
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:577:11)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usually this error is thrown when you're trying to `pipe()` something that's not a stream to `gulp.dest()`.

I see in your code `var imagemin = require('imagemin');` - are you sure you didn't mean to write `var imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin');`? **imagemin** won't return a proper `gulp` stream, but **gulp-imagemin** will.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I think that the problem was bacause i used gulp 4.0, bacause the same problem was wit autoprefixer and it solved with doungrade to gulp 3.9.1. I would like to try gulp-imagemin, but there is an issue with an installation, so it doesn't work.